# Update foreign key column from not null to null

Tags: sql

How I can update a foreign key column in a table from not null to null without having to recreate a table?

I tried to use this:

```
update tblProduct 
set ConsumerID not null
```

Please advise, thank you

Comment: MySql, SqlServer, Oracle,... what rdbms and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column] INTEGER NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tblProduct MODIFY ConsumerID BIGINT NOT NULL;
```

For more details about altering a MySQL table please visit [ALTER TABLE SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is altering data about the table and not data in the table, thus you need to alter the data schema.
So look at create and alter table statements

e.g. for Sybase (and MS Sql server)

```
alter table tblProduct modify ConsumerID integer NULL
```